# map and hover on a provinces, shows info about that particular province

Tags: jquery, css, svg

at the bottom of this link:
http://www.offerkhan.com/control4
you can see a section with a map that has lots of provinces. i intend to have a code that by hovering over every province, an information section become visible at the right side of that section. consider that im on wordpress platform and using ENFOLD theme.
tnx.

Comment: I'm considering what? Do you have a question?

Comment: We're gonna need some more code to give a thorough answer to this, rather than just a link to a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you provided a very weak question (for future reference you might want to review [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), from what I can understand you want to display some information when hovering on something else.

Utilising jQuery very simply you could give each "province" a unique `id` (such as `id="province2"`), and then use the following jQuery to change text when you hover on a specific "province":

```
$('#1').hover(function(){
$('.info').text('Here is a whole lot of interesting information about the first button (Info #1) that you just hovered!');
});

$('#2').hover(function(){
$('.info').text('Here is a whole lot of interesting information about the second button (Info #2) that you just hovered!');
});
```

Put simply, when you hover on a div, it changes the text in another div.

See a full working example here:
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gq6bp43z/4/)

***This may not be what you are looking for seeming as your question was so vague, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.***

Comment: tnx a lot. sorry im not a native english speaker! so the main problem was that in enfold i should change every $ symbol to jQuery!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped @AhmadR!